# Solr - Get facet counts of a field for every month

Tags: search, solr, lucene, analytics, faceted-search

I need to fetch the employees count by industry for every month . The query I tried is

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=<Text>&fq=status_created_at:[2011-12-31T4:00:00Z TO 2016-04-13T4:00:00Z] AND -company:(20 26 27 536)&facet=true&facet.field=company&facet.date=status_created_at&facet.date.start=2012-01-01T4:00:00Z&facet.date.end=2016-4-12T4:00:00Z&facet.date.gap=+1MONTH&fl=id&wt=json&rows=0&start=0&defType=dismax&qf=text
```

Its not working. Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: How is it not working? Provide the details

Comment: The above query gives the results separately - 1. results count for every industry for the specified period 2. results count for every month.
I want this to get combined. i.e., results count of industries for every month

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your requirements but I think [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) is what you need.

Comment: No. My requirement is diff one. I need result counts by company in every year like
{
2015: {"1":123, "2":412},
2014: {"1":123, "2":412},
}

The result is the no of counts for every industry in every year. How should I apply Facets to get this?

Comment: You cannot apply facets like this. You'll have to group. Go through the link I've put up.

Comment: Oh ok. Thx will look at it. Which one will be faster . Grouping or Facet?